# How to get the color of a point of scrollview?

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a scrollview in my application, from which I can able to get the point to which it gets scrolled using onScrollChanged(x,y).

I set the Rainbow color background to my scrollview. I just wants to know the color at that particular point to which it has scrolled.

example: color at  scrollView point(0,150)

Are there any methods or  other solution to get the color of a scrollview at a point. I have searched for this in SO,Google but did not find anything.

I didnt know how to get the color for a particular point in scrollview. can anyone please suggest me in completing this task.

Comment: Is this android code? Pls tag your question properly

Comment: `-(UIColor *)colorOfPoint:(CGPoint)point` I think it's Objective C style function not android / Java

Comment: are you asking conceptually how this objective-c code snip works?

Comment: yes, I just want to know how can I achieve this in android

Comment: May I suggest you at least add an android tag to this question. Objective-C and Java, although both OOP,are rather different from syntax to framework libraries etc.

Comment: I'm not sure if this SO question helps at all. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202266/showing-color-selected-from-an-image-on-touch-event-in-an-overlay)